# How to change web script to a set response format instead of allowing negotiation?

Tags: java, web-scraping, alfresco, alfresco-share

I just created a web script to get the ticket of Alfresco Share.

1. Created getticket.get.desc.xml

   ```xml
   <webscript>
       <shortname>Get User Ticket</shortname>
       <description>Personalized greeting</description>
       <url>/getticket</url>
       <authentication>user</authentication>
       <negotiate accept="text/html">html</negotiate>
       <negotiate accept="application/json">json</negotiate>
   </webscript>
   ```
2. Created `getticket.get.html.ftl` (Plain Text)

   ```
   ${session.getTicket()}
   ```

I am trying to access to it from a Java page. The request is missing some parameters that the web script requires to negotiate the response format. So I need to change my web script to a set response format instead of allowing negotiation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set response format by replacing your negotiation tag lines with following.
  extension

There are various response types allowed you can mention one of them json,html,atom are few examples.